# Read multiple json files into spark dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have multiple JSON files contains data structure as

```json
{
    "columns":["Column1","Column2","Column3"],
    "data":[
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9],
        [10,11,12]
    ]
}
```

I want to create a pyspark df.
Though I can achieve it using pandas using below code, but I want to read it in pyspark (multiple JSON files)

```py
df = pd.read_json('test.json', orient='split')
```

I tried it using Pandas

```py
df = pd.read_json('test.json', orient='split')
```

but I want to read in pyspark dataframe

Comment: if you have access to [pandas API on spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html#pandas-api-on-spark) in your spark version, you could try using the same code in that package

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can read a json file in PySpark. First you need save your json data in a file, like "file.json". Then you can use below code to convert json file to dataframe:

```
# Importing package
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType,BooleanType,DoubleType

# Implementing JSON File in PySpark
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName("PySpark Read JSON") \
    .getOrCreate()


# Reading multiline json file
multiline_dataframe = spark.read.option("multiline","true") \
                      .json("file.json")  # you need to specify full path for file.json
multiline_dataframe.show()
```

In case you perfommed some processing on your dataframe and you need to save it in another json file, you could use below code:

```
# Writing PySpark dataframe into JSON File
dataframe.write.mode('Overwrite').json("file2.json") # you need to specify full path for file2.json
```

Below is the result running on my vscode:
[image: Result]

Consider that PySpark is for big data and you see some warning in the result image that shows Hadoop is kind of a dependency for working of PySpark properly. The result shows that this json file has been read and is ready for data science operations. But if you want to show it in some specific tabular forms, you need to do more operation on dataframe.

Comment: i don't think this will help OP read the json files in the format he wants to.

Comment: I added the result image and some points about the result in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it can be read like pandas does, but i've got sort-of a hack. the idea is to read all the json files as is, and then transform it to look like a dataframe.

*note that it is intensive processing for large amounts of data.*

here's an example

```py
# input source folder having multiple json files will result in multiple rows
data_sdf = spark.read.option('multiLine', 'true'). \
    json('/path/to/files')

data_sdf. \
    groupBy('columns'). \
    agg(func.collect_list('data').alias('data_merge')). \
    withColumn('data', func.flatten('data_merge')). \
    withColumn('data_struct', 
               func.transform('data', lambda x, i: func.struct(i.alias('id'), x.alias('rows')))
               ). \
    selectExpr('columns', 'inline(data_struct)'). \
    withColumn('zipped', func.arrays_zip('columns', 'rows')). \
    selectExpr('id', 'inline(zipped)'). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('columns'). \
    agg(func.first('rows')). \
    orderBy('id'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-------+-------+-------+
# |id |Column1|Column2|Column3|
# +---+-------+-------+-------+
# |0  |1      |2      |3      |
# |1  |4      |5      |6      |
# |2  |7      |8      |9      |
# |3  |10     |11     |12     |
# +---+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

explanation

the files when read will produce 2 columns - `data` and `columns`

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|columns                    |data                                           |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|[Column1, Column2, Column3]|[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]|
+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

the `data_struct` column adds an ID to each of the row arrays within the `data` array.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data_struct                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{0, [1, 2, 3]}, {1, [4, 5, 6]}, {2, [7, 8, 9]}, {3, [10, 11, 12]}]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

then explode the `data_struct` column and create new rows with each ID and row array. so, each row will have an array of columns and an array for the row. to collectively explode the column and data row, we zipped the two arrays to create an array of struct (named `zipped`), which is finally exploded to get a linear dataframe. *(note - there are two explosions)*

```
+---------------------------+---+------------+---------------------------------------------+
|columns                    |id |rows        |zipped                                       |
+---------------------------+---+------------+---------------------------------------------+
|[Column1, Column2, Column3]|0  |[1, 2, 3]   |[{Column1, 1}, {Column2, 2}, {Column3, 3}]   |
|[Column1, Column2, Column3]|1  |[4, 5, 6]   |[{Column1, 4}, {Column2, 5}, {Column3, 6}]   |
|[Column1, Column2, Column3]|2  |[7, 8, 9]   |[{Column1, 7}, {Column2, 8}, {Column3, 9}]   |
|[Column1, Column2, Column3]|3  |[10, 11, 12]|[{Column1, 10}, {Column2, 11}, {Column3, 12}]|
+---------------------------+---+------------+---------------------------------------------+

+---+-------+----+
|id |columns|rows|
+---+-------+----+
|0  |Column1|1   |
|0  |Column2|2   |
|0  |Column3|3   |
|1  |Column1|4   |
|1  |Column2|5   |
|1  |Column3|6   |
|2  |Column1|7   |
|2  |Column2|8   |
|2  |Column3|9   |
|3  |Column1|10  |
|3  |Column2|11  |
|3  |Column3|12  |
+---+-------+----+
```

this data can now be pivoted to get the final dataframe.